# How to debug SessionNotCreatedException?

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

How to debug `SessionNotCreatedException` in Firefox/Selenium?

```
1501668018402   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:6748
    1501668025463   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
    1501668037220   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 53205
    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{moz:firefoxOptions={binary=Optional.empty, args=[], legacy=null, logLevel=null, prefs={}, profile=null}}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{moz:firefoxOptions={binary=Optional.empty, args=[], legacy=null, logLevel=null, prefs={}, profile=null}}]
    Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800'
    System info: host: 'CELKON-RND-PC', ip: '192.168.1.6', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
    Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:121)
        at testpack.testclass.main(testclass.java:16)
```

Comment: Please learn to use the formatting tools here - the toolbar button you need to format log/code looks like `{}`.

Comment: You'll probably need to provide some additional context if people are going to be able to help you. Is the `testcalss.java` something you've written? What is happening on line 16 - any clues there? Please edit your post to add this information.

Comment: Please consider bumping up `Selenium` from `3.3.1` to `3.4.0`. Thanks